# Can I use GTest to test a single, simple function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm trying to get familiar to gtest and so I want to test a single function like this:

```
int fun(int x=6){
return x;
}
```

I'm writing a code like this:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "iostream"

int fun(int x=6){
return x;
}

TEST(FunTest, defaultTest) {
   EXPECT_EQ(6, fun());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

But I get about a million errors. Can you help me on this?

Comment: We can't really help unless we know what the million errors are.

Comment: This code works fine on my machine. The only issue is it should be `<iostream>`. It's probably a linking issue.

Comment: No not at all, a linking issue (I just forgot to copy-paste <iostream>). I guess, the problem is that I'm trying to get my code compiled through Geany, isn't it?

Comment: -1 for "I get about a million errors". Please try to post questions that are actually answerable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least,

```
#include "iostream"
```

should be

```
#include <iostream>
```

When you run Google test, you need to make sure that the gtest libs are correctly linked.
Quoting from [Google test documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer)

> Setting up a New Test Project
>
> To write a test program using Google Test, you need to compile Google Test into a library and link your test with it. We provide build files for some popular build systems: msvc/ for Visual Studio, xcode/ for Mac Xcode, make/ for GNU make, codegear/ for Borland C++ Builder, and the autotools script (deprecated) and CMakeLists.txt for CMake (recommended) in the Google Test root directory. If your build system is not on this list, you can take a look at make/Makefile to learn how Google Test should be compiled (basically you want to compile src/gtest-all.cc with GTEST_ROOT and GTEST_ROOT/include in the header search path, where GTEST_ROOT is the Google Test root directory).
>
> Once you are able to compile the Google Test library, you should create a project or build target for your test program. Make sure you have GTEST_ROOT/include in the header search path so that the compiler can find "gtest/gtest.h" when compiling your test. Set up your test project to link with the Google Test library (for example, in Visual Studio, this is done by adding a dependency on gtest.vcproj).

Comment: Ok, that's the problem, fair enough I can't get my code compiled. Thank you!

Comment: @iiirxs try to follow their instructions, you should be able to get there.